# Combinatorics: Number of subsets of $[n]$ so that each two have a common element

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Let $\mathcal F$ be a collection of all subsets of $[n]$ so that each two subsets have a common element and are same size of $k$ ($n \ge 2k$). Prove that $$|\mathcal F| \le {n - 1 \choose k - 1}$$

I have been able to prove that if all those subsets have a common ellement then $\mathcal F = {n-1 \choose k-1}$. But I am struggling with the rest of the problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: What set is [n]?  It looks like a modulo class.  But of what?  [n] = { n + j*M} but what is M?  And what is k.  n >= 2k???? what is k?

Comment: This is the famous Erdos-Ko-Rado Theorem. There is a very short, nice proof with the probabilistic method.

Comment: [N] is a set of n elements

Comment: "A collection, F, of $k \in X$, so that each two in F have a property".  Doesn't actually make any sense.  You can't collect *all* of something with a property that will depend upon *which* of the things you collect.  If I try to select all sets with 1 element so that any two have an elment in common, the I can only pick 1 set, but which one depends upon... which one I pick.  So I can't select *all* of them (because then any two will not have an element in common.

Comment: Not,  "all" subsets of $[n]$ but *a* collection of *some* subsets of [n] so that that condition is met.  By the way, I have never seen the notation [n] to mean a set of n elements before in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** Consider sets $S_j=\{j,j+1,\dots,j+k-1\}$, with addition mod $n$ and $0\leq j\leq n-1$. Then at most $k$ of the $S_j$ are in $\mathcal F$.

*Proof.* Take some $S_{\ell}\in\mathcal F$. Any other $S_j$ with $S_j\cap S_{\ell}\neq\emptyset$ can be partitioned into $k-1$ pairs $(S_{\ell-j},S_{\ell+k-j})$ with $S_{\ell-j}\cap S_{\ell+k-j}=\emptyset$. The result now follows. $\square$

Now choose a permutation $\pi$ of $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ and some $0\leq i\leq n-1$, at random and independently. Let $S=\{\pi(i),\pi(i+1),\dots,\pi(i+k-1)\}$, with addition mod $n$. Conditioning on $\pi$, by our lemma, $\mathbb P(S\in\mathcal F)\leq\frac{k}{n}$, so $$\frac{k}{n}\geq\mathbb P(S\in\mathcal F)=\frac{|\mathcal F|}{\binom{n}{k}}\implies|\mathcal F|\leq\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$